# In the United States, how are Presidential campaigns organized?

Tags: united-states, campaigning

What does the organizational structure of a U.S. presidential campaign typically look like?

Are there certain positions or officers that typically exist? Are there common "departments"? How do these departments typically report to executive campaign leadership?

I am sure there is some variance between different campaigns. However, like any other kind of "industry" there are likely similar structures and positions that commonly exist.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_campaign_staff#Structure_of_a_campaign

Comment: @user4012 Please do not provide answers in comments.

Comment: Are you asking how the candidates structure their respective campaign organizations, or how the campaign is organized and administered by the government?

Comment: @indigochild - it was more of a lazy way of asking "please clarify what should be in the answer that the Wikipedia does not cover" :)

Comment: @user4012 Gotcha!  The information in the wikipedia article would answer my question, if it were true. Unfortunately the article is poorly sourced, and even the existing sources are of dubious quality themselves.